# How does COBOL actually accept numeric values?

Tags: cobol

I have a very simple COBOL code here that has a given input data and output data. The problem is that, it shows an error on line 60 which is the `MOVE STUD-AGE TO AGE-OUT.` and everytime I run OpenCOBOLIDE, I always get and error which is:

```
libcob: test.cob: 60: 'STUD-AGE' not numeric: '  '
WARNING - Implicit CLOSE of STUDENT-OUT ('C:\STUD-OUT.DAT')
WARNING - Implicit CLOSE of STUDENT-IN ('C:\STUD-IN.DAT')
```

And I don't know exactly what's wrong with it. Here is supposedly the input file I created:

```
----5---10---15---20---25---30---35---40--
00-123345 ALISON MARTIN WOLF       1912056
00-789012 KEN DENNIOS ROME         1914156
00-345678 JACK ADRIAN TOCKSIN      1622234
00-901234 EJHAYZ ALONEY            2045645
00-567890 CHARLES JOHN GUINNIVER   1813243
00-123457 JEAN MICHAEL YARTER      2034253
```

Here's the code to it:

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. SAMPLE.
   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
   INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
   FILE-CONTROL.
       SELECT STUDENT-IN ASSIGN TO "C:\STUD-IN.DAT".
       SELECT STUDENT-OUT ASSIGN TO "C:\STUD-OUT.DAT".
   DATA DIVISION.
   FILE SECTION.
   FD  STUDENT-IN.
   01  STUD-REC.
       02 STUD-NO PIC X(10).
       02 STUD-NAME PIC X(25).
       02 STUD-AGE PIC 99.
       02 STUD-ALLOWANCE PIC 999V99.
   FD  STUDENT-OUT.
   01  PRINT-REC PIC X(80).
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01  HDG-1.
       02 FILLER PIC X(20) VALUE SPACES.
       02 FILLER PIC X(22) VALUE "WILLOW PARK UNIVERSITY".
       02 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE " OF MADAGASCAR".
   01  HDG-2.
       02 FILLER PIC X(9) VALUE SPACES.
       02 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "STUDENT NUMBER".
       02 FILLER PIC X(8) VALUE SPACES.
       02 FILLER PIC X(12) VALUE "STUDENT NAME".
       02 FILLER PIC X(15) VALUE SPACES.
       02 FILLER PIC X(3) VALUE "AGE".
       02 FILLER PIC X(8) VALUE SPACES.
       02 FILLER PIC X(9) VALUE "ALLOWANCE".

   01  PRINT-LINE.
       02 FILLER PIC X(9) VALUE SPACES.
       02 SNO-OUT PIC X(10).
       02 FILLER PIC X(12) VALUE SPACES.
       02 SNAME-OUT PIC X(25).
       02 FILLER PIC X(2) VALUE SPACE.
       02 AGE-OUT PIC Z9.
       02 FILLER PIC X(9) VALUE SPACES.
       02 ALL-OUT PIC ZZZ.99.
   01  E-O-F PIC XXX VALUE "NO".
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.

       OPEN INPUT STUDENT-IN
         OUTPUT STUDENT-OUT.

       WRITE PRINT-REC FROM HDG-1 BEFORE 1 LINE.
       WRITE PRINT-REC FROM HDG-2 AFTER 2 LINES.
       MOVE SPACES TO PRINT-REC.
       WRITE PRINT-REC AFTER 1 LINE.

       PERFORM READ-RTN UNTIL E-O-F = "YES".
       PERFORM CLOSE-RTN.

   READ-RTN.
       READ STUDENT-IN AT END MOVE "YES" TO E-O-F.
       MOVE STUD-NO TO SNO-OUT.
       MOVE STUD-NAME TO SNAME-OUT.
       MOVE STUD-AGE TO AGE-OUT.
       MOVE STUD-ALLOWANCE TO ALL-OUT.

       WRITE PRINT-REC FROM PRINT-LINE AFTER 1 LINE.
       

   CLOSE-RTN.
       CLOSE STUDENT-IN, STUDENT-OUT.
       STOP RUN.
```

What I want to achieve is just to output the file correctly but the error only inputs the `HDG-1` and then the rest blank.

Comment: The error tells you that the STUDENT-AGE consists of spaces.  Do you have any title lines or blank lines in your input file?

Comment: The input file is exactly what it is. STUD-NO is 9 digits + 1 space. STUD-NAME has exactly 25 digits including the spaces and the numbers which is age and the allowance part is exactly 2 digits and 999V99. I don't see anything wrong with my input file and as you may have edited it, you can see that it has the exact and correct measures.

Comment: Okay wait I might correct myself, does COBOL really need to be like in a straight line when inputting data? Like for example:

`00-123345 ALISON MARTIN WOLF       191205600-789012 KEN DENNIOS ROME         1914156`

I did this and I think it worked correctly(?)

Comment: I think you have to take carriage control characters into account when specifying the length of the input records.  Yes, I added the ruler line to your input because I got tired of counting characters.

Comment: And my default comment for OpenCOBOLIDE users: make sure you use a current GnuCOBOL version (which would be either 2.2 or a 3.1-pre-version). If you need help with that check about that with the [community forum](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnucobol/discussion/help/).
BTW: That's a *very* good first post at SO - congrats!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question: COBOL accept numeric data however you define it.
So for "text data" (as long as it isn't UTF-16 or another multibyte encoded file) `PIC 99` (which says "two digits in the default `USAGE DISPLAY` - so one byte per digit) is perfectly fine.

As with *every* other language: "never trust input data" is something I can recommend. For example: someone could run this program with a file that was saved with an `UTF-8` encoded character in the name and then it "looks" right but the code has an unexpected  shift in its data. For COBOL things like `FUNCTION TEST-NUMVAL(inp)` [ignores spaces and allows decimal-point] or `IS NUMERIC` (strict class test) can be useful.
Using data-check you could for example also skip empty lines or leading/trailing extra data (temporary rulers, headline, summary, ...).

For the actual problem:
It looks like you feed the program with a "common" text file, but you actually did not specify this so your COBOL implementation uses the default `SEQUENTIAL`. Because of the missing check of the input data you did not spot this directly.
To align expectations and code:

```
       SELECT STUDENT-IN  ASSIGN TO "C:\STUD-IN.DAT"
                          ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
       SELECT STUDENT-OUT ASSIGN TO "C:\STUD-OUT.DAT"
                          ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
```

Comment: This actually answered my question! What I'm missing is the `ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.` and now it works! I believe that I'm getting the error because I did not indicated the said line. Also, to my dumbest attempt, I had to one line the data I had on the DAT file which is a mistake. This is great thanks!